# foreach code in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to iterate through an xml document to get its values. See the given code

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $key1=>$value1 /*($xml->children() as $second_gen)*/ ) {
    echo ' 1 ' .$key1.' '.$value1.'<br>';

    foreach ($second_gen as $key2=>$value2) {
        echo ' ___2 ' .$key2.' '.$value2.'<br>';

    }
}
```

So what I want to do is to make `$second_gen` equals to the children of the each current iteration of the loop. I was able to do this by putting it in the foreach, but this prevented me from using key/value. So is there any solution to get both?
Thanks!

Comment: What if you replace `$second_gen` by `$value1` ?

Comment: WOW man, you're the best! (Y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in a foreach loop equals to the value itself. So if you leave out the `$key =>` part or not doesn't change the `$value`:

```
foreach ( $xml->children() as $key1 => $value1 )
{
    foreach ( $value1->children() as $key2 = $value2 )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```